# Temporarily Disabling Auto-Scaling Group's Scale-Down Only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Is there a way to temporarily disable an auto-scaling group's scale-down, whilst still allowing it to terminate unhealthy instances?

Per its [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-suspend-resume-processes.html), suspending the **Terminate** scaling process will disable scale-in, but for my scenario, has the undesired side effect of also disabling termination of unhealthy instances.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, since you only wish this behavior to be temporary, is to change the **Minimum** number of instances to be the current (Desired) number of instances. This will disable scale-in because the minimum number of instances has been reached.

When you wish to **resume** scale-in, set the Minimum back to the normal value.

Comment: That is currently our back-up plan if `suspend_process` won't work. The reason is that we don't have a good value for **Minimum** (as opposed to allowing scale-up to naturally increase capacity as needed)